# How can we set dynamic "redirect_uri" parameter value in dropbox-api integration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dropbox, dropbox-api

I need to set URL(s) into dropbox for `redirect_uri` parameters.

Our application support dynamic domain URL(s).
URL prefix define by user and suffix will be constant. And prefix will change at any time.
e.g. Format(https://{**prefix**-testapplication.com})

## 1 : Application URL : `https://abc-testapplication.com`

## 2 : Application URL : `https://def-testapplication.com`

In an above example, we need to mentioned `redirect_uri` into `DropBox` for navigation.

Mention `redirect_uri` as below image.
[image]
As per above image, we can configure url value at a time only.

So problem is that, how we can support dynamic URL?

Thanks in an advance.

Answer (score 1):

As a security feature, Dropbox OAuth 2 redirect URIs must be pre-registered exactly. Wildcard and dynamic registrations are not supported.

One thing you may be able to do instead is to use one static redirect URI but encode the necessary information in the `state` parameter, and decode it after the redirect back to your app, to handle it as necessary (e.g., redirect to the relevant domain):

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize

Alternatively, you could forgo using a redirect URI entirely. With the "code" flow, you can omit `redirect_uri` and have the user copy and paste the code manually.

Comment: In first approach I don't think so my query resolve with state parameter.
In second approach, How i will get access_token for upload/download files or without access_token i can access those apis?

Comment: how we can overcome the value of redirect_uri in both approach?

Comment: @JeetBhatt When using the "code" flow, the `redirect_uri` is actually optional. If you don't provide it, the authorization code will just be presented to the user directly on the Dropbox web site. The user would then need to copy it from the Dropbox web site and paste it into your app. Your app would then use it with [/oauth2/token](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-token) to get an access token.

Comment: manual steps not work overhear.... we need to implement complete automate process...  i.e.1) in our app user click on dropbox activate button 2) user redirect to dropbox site 3) user entered dropbox registered credentials 4) provide allow access 5) then redirect back to our application
If we can follow code flow then user stuck on dropbox site.. like authorize submit... then how user can back to out application?

Comment: @JeetBhatt If you need to have this happen automatically, then you need to use a redirect URI. Since you can't use a dynamic redirect URI, you'd need to use a static redirect URI to your own static server and then perform your own redirect to the relevant domain.